# d3.js line chart not rendering stocks line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a hobby project site with PHP which stores stocks data. The data will be outputed as a fancy line chart like this one http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245
I have tried to search for a tutorial like that one with explanation but haven't had any success.

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vartox/5Ur3j/1/

This bit I'm not sure of at all. Thanks in advance

```
x.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return parseDate(d.date); }));
y.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return parseFloat(d.close); }));


svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Price ($)");

svg.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've mixed up your scales in lines 29-30 --

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(parseFloat(d.date)); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(parseDate(d.close)); });
```

should be

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(parseDate(d.date)); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(parseFloat(d.close)); });
```